# Order various elements floating on the right

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a nav bar floating right, and a logout image that must also float right, being on the right side of the nav bar.

Even when both are floating right, bar always takes the last place, which should be for the logout image.

Here's a working example (take "X" as logout image): http://jsfiddle.net/c2ccB/

HTML is built positioning first the nav bar and then the logout image:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        ...........

    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="logout"></div>
```

And Style has both floating right (see jsfiddle for an extended style version):

```
nav{
    float: right;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #DFDFDF , white 80%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:  1px solid #9F9D9D;
    margin: 42px 80px 0 0;
}

.logout{
    background-image: url(images/logout.png);
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: [Just swap them areound](http://jsfiddle.net/c2ccB/1/) Job done

Comment: jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/c2ccB/4/ if you dont want to swipe you may play with position on logout image

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you don't want to change the order in the html elements, is to just wrap them in a `<div>` with `float:right;`, then change the individual elements to  `float:left;`

Here's a fiddle for it : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2ccB/5/)

Comment: Thank you for your attention, at least changing element's order solved it.